# Как в UBUNTU установить phpmyadmin на php 7.1

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, phpmyadmin

Я установил в UBUNTU 14.04 apache2+php7.1+mysql . При попытке установить на всё это phpmyadmin, он устанавливается только с php5.6 и выдаёт всякую ерунду при обращении к нему в браузере. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: почему не хочешь воспользоваться нормальной программой, хоть `mysql workbench`, хоть `SQLyog`, хоть какой-то подобной?

Comment: "PHP 7 is supported since phpMyAdmin 4.6, PHP 7.1 is supported since 4.6.5." какую версию ставите то?

Comment: Я ставлю phpmyadmin с помощью команды sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext . Выдаётся сообщение "нет модуля mysqli", хотя он установлен. Вот сообщение: "The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration". Раньше у меня был установлен php 5.6, но я его снёс, но phpmyadmin пытается сослаться на его конфигурацию.

Comment: устанавливайте пакет `phpmyadmin` оттуда же, откуда взяли и пакет `php7.1`

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, в основном репозитории 14.04 нет php7.1 (как и совместимого с ним phpMyAdmin). Возможно вам проще будет ручками установить phpMyAdmin подходящей версии.

Comment: Если пишет "The mysqli extension is missing" зачем вы пытаетесь ставь phpmyadmin? Вы сперва с БД разберитесь. Возможно в ini файле не настроен mysqli

Comment: php -m | grep mysql выдаёт: mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql

Answer (score 1):

Я добился того чтобы phpmyadmin заработал. 
sudo apt install php7.1-mysql - устанавливаем mysql под php 7.1
В файле /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini находим блок "Dinamic extensions" и добавляем в конец: extension=mysqli.so, либо раскомментируем эту запись, если она закомменчена.